Why Simple Present Tense?
Global warming
This is an excerpt from a girl's article in which she describes her horrifying family vacation. A polar bear tried to attack the group at Ella Island, Greenland:

A few days after our return to England, someone in the group posted pictures praising the ranger who had saved us. This led to a huge debate on social media about what had happened. Some people were outraged, saying we had no right to be in this polar bear's territory and that we might have killed it. After all, polar bears are an endangered species.

In the final sentence, the narrator uses the simple present tense; why? Could she say it in the simple past tense ?

In English, the present tense is used to express general truths. Polar bears are an endangered species. This is generally true. Putting it in the past tense, "polar bears were an endangered species", implies that they were endangered at the time of the debate, but are no longer endangered.

@oshitgorrilas - Maybe we can use either simple present or simple past as suggested by the answer below. In the future it might not be an endangered species.

Edit
The statement

After all, polar bears are an endangered species.

was the girl's.  The girl used the present tense to reflect the polar bear situation at the point of writing.
If the statement (minus the After all) had been from those outraged, that is, prior to the writing, both tenses would have been possible with or without backshift:

Some people were outraged, saying we had no right to be in this polar bear's territory and that we might have killed it[; they added that] polar bears are (or were) an endangered species.

or

[The people outraged also reminded me that] polar bears are (or were) an endangered species.


No, because they continue to be an endangered species past the simple past used in the article.

Thanks, @Lambie.  You are right.  I have edited my answer. +1 for you.
